# Plural error or set phrase? -- a Games for everyone

Tags: grammatical-number

This job ad [posted by the London 2012 Organising Committee](https://locogrecruitment.london2012.com/jobs/main?cmd=reqDisplayJobDetails&jobId=2270) ends with the sentence:

> London 2012 is a Games for everyone, so we want you to apply regardless of your age, gender, ethnicity, sexual orientation, faith or disability.

Is "a Games" a set phrase?

Comment: They misspelled organizing (*ducks*)

Comment: No they didn't. That's the way it's spelled in British English.

Comment: @cwallenpoole: you mean, they ***misspelt*** it!

Comment: "spelled" may be spelled "spelled" in certain parts of the world, no?

Comment: What's with this editing of questions? First, `Third Idiot` edits my question and adds a paltry colon before the quote (which I don't believe is required). Then that edit disappears and instead I find an edit by `Ham and Bacon`, with just the same flipping colon and a link to a tweet. Isn't it a policy at SE to restrict single character edits? WTF? What's the purpose? The placement of the colon is disputable, I feel. And even if it were important, which it is not, it's really not required to understand the question. So what's the hidden agenda here? Exposure? Rep? Just because you can?

Comment: @teylyn: nobody has added a twitter link to your post; the fact that the question has been tweeted just happens to appear on the edit history page (odd, to my mind, but there you go). Nor are there two edits - just that *Third Idiot* has changed username to *Ham and Bacon*. I agree that the additional colon is unnecessary... but sometimes people seem to feel strongly about certain points; when they do this to my questions/answers, if the edit isn't actually wrong/worse, I tend to just leave it (and assume that doing so makes someone, somewhere, marginally happier :)

Comment: @teylyn: Obviously *Third Idiot/Ham and Bacon* is just one person. As is everyone else here at any given moment. Most of us prolly stick with the name we started with - but who hasn't ever wanted to wipe the slate and start afresh? Personally, I think the odd thing isn't what *one* guy happens to do (Exposure? Rep? Who cares?). It's that *four* people upvoted my answer, but only *one* person upvoted your question. Now *that's* a conspiracy! Anyway, I'm now (somewhat shamefacedly) going to belatedly upvote the question... :)

Comment: Ta, FF! I was totally thrown by the identity change "Third Idiot/Ham and Bacon". After all, that is not immediately obvious. How come that everyone else seems to clock it but me? I'm starting to value the forums/Q&A sites/Discusion boards that don't allow a change of user ID after registration.

Comment: @teylyn: I knew it was possible to change your username "on the fly", so to speak, but I didn't know it applied here until @psmears flagged it up. I just thought there was an increasing tendency for some posters to do things I don't necessarily endorse. But in the end, people get rep through upvotes from "everyone else", and you can't argue with everyone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's neither a 'set phrase' nor an error. It's just a creative and potentially attention-grabbing short form for **The Olympic Games** (or *An Olympic Games* if you want to nit-pick, but I'm sure the guy who wrote that was pefectly happy with his work).